# Getting confusing error for Identity Toolkit mfaEnrollment.start request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, multi-factor-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

After following the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/accounts.mfaEnrollment/start?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22idToken%22%3A%22rlKHPzwECDPa7LSxIB7JMckDzGb2%22%2C%22tenantId%22%3A%22mx-sand-admin-6i3sc%22%2C%22phoneEnrollmentInfo%22%3A%7B%22phoneNumber%22%3A%22%2B14802722002%22%2C%22recaptchaToken%22%3A%2203AAYGu2QUhssk3ojpKIFARbUu0naYHLx5PGfKeqPTA3wyypKrIt1_QV2rUTAF6BtT-v25tC5VokkFZtWptCLu1XxsoK6hbjQY_Ld3Jldid61aqFP3Cs7Gsv3TWj7mukUq5tWrOqHQ4vZR3r3ifiYoGdFZPys3qZ1R7ajVlhWCuiox6W7KoGzZRzwEMwZ90rN5MWsZT9cqRrFsvxOBX5zr-Ol4gW2iPvMj_BoDrGayHkrWYlkLqDqziIQncNYz-QAn2m1HcfFMn-BVKC9trgHFJqXS_669XXRJqpdLfd36fNYKP-rA36ro5XP635lPAFO3SnbqMhMMJ6dqhfFVS3xHuPrII6k1EqFYMIfKM9pkgaPxPNTyza7rwAFl_DsrhHQ_SLBGrRKYV7o-1M_Y_P4U5vSXfAxniBcxlbEj5gpxzmaofUJ63Lu2_C1-Oh837T7sI1zprOI_RqkERp38ifdPuLyUHO-dNOq_i0FaQUwDR0MtWNTpiqqQRIm8Xv_eWWxPfcSWo5uyEcyPkur_5rvTrsT3IKufzcK13g%22%7D%7D%7D), I am getting the below error. This error does not make sense as I am using the exact same access token creation process as I am for GIP tenant creation and it works just fine there.

```
Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
```

My body looks like this

```
def build_body(params)
 {
    :idToken => params[:id_token],
    :tenantId => ::ENV.fetch("DEFAULT_SHARED_GIP_TENANT"),
    :phoneEnrollmentInfo => {
      :phoneNumber => params[:phone_number],
      :recaptchaToken => params[:recaptcha_token]
    }
 }.to_json
end
```

My enroll call:

```
def enroll(body)
  access_token = ::Actions::Gip::AccessToken.new.call.success
  ::Net::HTTP.post(
    URI("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/accounts/mfaEnrollment:start"),
    body,
    { :Authorization => "Bearer #{access_token}", "Content-Type" => "application/json" }
  )
end
```

My access token action:

```
def fetch_token(json_string)
  ::Rails.cache.fetch("portal.gip.access_token", :expires_in => 55.minutes) do
    scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/identitytoolkit", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
      :json_key_io => StringIO.new(json_string), # Service account creds
      :scope => scope
    )
    token = authorizer.fetch_access_token!
    token["access_token"]
  end
end
```

The service account has the roles Firebase Admin, Identity Platform Admin, and Identity Toolkit Admin